# DB_NAME(database_id) return null when executed through linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to execute below query :

```
SELECT DB_NAME(Database_id) FROM [linked_servername].MASTER.SYS.DATABASE_MIRRORING
WHERE database_id > 4 and mirroring_role = 1
```

But I am getting Result as NULL means database name is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope of `DB_NAME()` is limited to the local instance.  It only applies to databases that exist on the server where you are running the query.

Instead of using `DB_NAME()`, you should join to `sys.databases` with four part naming, as in the following example:

```
SELECT DB.name 
FROM [linked_servername].master.sys.database_mirroring DM
    INNER JOIN [linked_servername].master.sys.databases DB ON DM.database_id = DB.database_id
WHERE DM.database_id > 4 and mirroring_role = 1;
```

I notice you have capitalized portions of the query including the `master` database, the `sys` schema, and the `database_mirroring` system table.  These objects exist in lower case, so you should code them in lower case.  For SQL Servers that have a case-sensitive collation, specifying the correct case is [important for many reasons](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-careless-about-case/).

Answer (score 0):

Another occasion when db_name() can return null is when you are dealing with the `resources` database which has `database_id = 32767`

for example:

```
select distinct case when database_id = 32767 
                     then 'resourceDb' 
                      else db_name(database_id) 
                 end, count(*)
from sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors b with(nolock)
group by database_id
order by 1 desc
```

[image]